# solaris test driver crashes

Tags: drivers, solaris

In solaris I wrote a driver and it is crashing.. But my solaris kernel is also getting crashed because of it. The driver is getting loaded every time the system resets and kernel is dumping core and reboots.. How to stop the loading of the crashing driver whenever the system reboots?

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you aren't using Solaris 10 (or newer) which implement failsafe booting and has so many other improvements. Anyway, the simplest method to recover your system would be to boot on an OpenSolaris(/illumos) SPARC live CD like Milax ( http://genunix.org/distributions/dss/milax032sparc.iso ) or similar, mount your Solaris 9 root filesystem and remove your bogus driver from there.

When done, you might want to implement failsafe boot like explained here:

http://wikis.sun.com/display/BigAdmin/Back+port+Solaris+10+failsafe+feature+to+Solaris+9+and+below